# how to best account for whitespaces (#text) childnode compatibility in javascript

Tags: javascript, whitespace, compatibility, nodes, onmouseover

I have code in one of the webpages as below -

```
<li><a href="howto.php" id="howto"><img id="imgHowTo" src="imghowto.png" />HOW TO</a></li>
```

This is the expected behavior -
on hovering the list item, the image should change to imgHowTo-new.png and the "HOW TO" text color should change to green (initially it was blue).

Now I do not have permission to modify the html or the css, and i have to achieve the expected behaviour using javascript.

I used the below js code -

```
document.getElementById("imgHowTo").onmouseover = HoverIn;
function HoverIn(){
newImg = "imgHowTo-new.png"
this.src = newImg;
this.parentNode.style.color = green;
}
```

Now on hovering on the icon, the image changes and text color is rightly updated. But I want these changes to happen when mouse hovers on the "list item" and not on the image/ text alone. How can i do this without changing the css/html? Also, how do i account for the presence of whitespace (#text) compatibility issue when childNodes are used to access the elements? I need this to work in all browsers.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *can* do something like this:

```
(function() {
    var imgHowTo = document.getElementById("imgHowTo"),
        a        = imgHowTo.parentNode,
        li       = a.parentNode;
    li.onmouseover = HoverIn;
    function HoverIn(){
        imgHowTo.src = "imgHowTo-new.png";
        a.style.color = green;
    }
})();
```

(Note that I put the whole thing in a function, to avoid creating global variables.) I'd be concerned by how fragile it is, because it's very closely tied to the HTML structure, but it should work for the structure you've listed.

What that does is find the `img`, then find the anchor you want to change the color of and the `li` you want to watch for the mouse event on, then hook up the event. Since you're only moving *up* the hierarchy, you don't have to worry about intermediate text nodes in this specific case, although that is something you frequently have to deal with when moving *down* the hierarchy or across siblings.

Somewhat off-topic, but note that `mouseover` fires repeatedly, so your `HoverIn` function will get called over and over again. That doesn't really matter much because once it's done its thing doing it again is harmless, but still...

---

Separately, for this sort of thing, it's really worth using a good JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They smooth over a lot of browser differences for you, offer tools to help you skip over text nodes (you mentioned being concerned about that), and just generally provide a lot of pre-built, pre-tested utility stuff that leaves you free to concentrate on your specific work.

For example, using (say) jQuery, I'd probably make the code a little less sensitive to HTML changes (not a lot, but some):

```
(function() {
    var imgHowTo = $("#imgHowTo"),
        a        = imgHowTo.closest("a"),
        li       = a.closest("li");
    if (li[0]) { // If the structure isn't there, we skip the event handler
        li.mouseover(HoverIn);
    }

    function HoverIn() {
        imgHowTo[0].src = "imgHowTo-new.png";
        a.css("color", "green");
    }
})();
```

That's *slightly* more friendly to small HTML changes because it doesn't assume that the anchor is the *immediate* parent of the image, or that the list item is the *immediate* parent of the anchor. So if someone wraps the anchor in a div, for instance, it still works.

Using jQuery, Prototype, or probably several of the others also gives you the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events (which are normally IE-only, but they're emulated by libraries like jQuery and Prototype on other browsers), which are useful for hover effects because they don't bubble.

Comment: thanks a ton! that was a huge help.

I just built upon your solution, and find that the image is changed correctly when the list item is hovered upon. But the color of text is not getting changed.

"this" represents the "li" now.

and i used: this.style.color = red;
but the style of the text is not getting updated on hovering the list item. what gives?

Comment: @arun: Glad that helped! The anchor probably has its own color, so it doesn't matter what color you assign to the `li` because the anchor will override it. That's why in my example I assigned to the anchor's style instead. (I didn't use `this` at all, in fact, because all the changes you were making were to descendant elements, so I just used them directly.)

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("imgHowTo").parentNode.parentNode.onmouseover
```

Comment: Now how do i navigate to the child elements while solving the whitespace childNode issue?

Comment: @arunnair, the issue you speak of is a problem only when using nextSibling or previousSibling, so Manuel's solution should work for you.

Comment: @arunnair: Yes, as Amaan said, when you go *up* the hierarchy, you don't have to worry about text nodes (since they can't contain elements); you worry about text nodes when going across (siblings) or down (descendants).